rkhunter results: /usr/bin/curl modification time issue
I got some weird rkhunter results today. I have definitely checked it since the current file modification time, and this never showed up.
File: /usr/bin/curl
Current hash: b087a641efd1a2e916f9f163f7c639855bf09b0039c1d8fa3e441411c1528a19
Stored hash : 938886d18c5b296a8345da265428b6a944aad7b4de41313a38085d89a4217e19
Current inode: 947079    Stored inode: 930766
Current file modification time: 1730902689 (06-Nov-2024 14:18:09)
Stored file modification time : 1725622031 (06-Sep-2024 12:27:11)

I installed the program kolourpaint last night, didn't do a --propupd afterwards, so that's probably it, but the modification date is from way before I've done my last few rkhunter checks. What the heck is going on here?
